# matrix can contain elements of different class

Tags: r

I am a newbie to R programming. In the tutorial for R language , I found matrix can not have elements from different classes.

But I am able to create a matrix as follows:

```
x<-matrix(list(1,"2",TRUE,1+1i),nrow=2,ncol=2)
```

Please explain what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A matrix is implemented as a vector with a `dim` attribute. A list is technically a type of vector, so what you created is "legal" in that sense.

But it's not very useful because most functions that take a matrix as input expect the matrix to be an atomic type (a list is a recursive-type object).

Comment: So can  I use matrix instead of dataframe which can contains elements of different class?

Comment: @jatinkashyap: You *can*, but you *should not*.  Like I said in my answer, most functions will expect all matrix elements to be the same type.

Comment: Thanks for the response @joshua. I got it

Comment: Does the elements inside the matrix I have created in the question coerced to a single type ??

Comment: @jatinkashyap: no. Look at the output of `str(x)`.